# Group objects in blender

Tags: groups

There´s a way of grouping SVG objects in blender like in Illustrator or Inkscape, where when I have to move the object the entire group move´s on together, without having to append that object to the main object?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sort of.

Select all the object you want to group.

Press ctrl+G, you will notice a green outline appear around them.

Now in future, if you wish to manipulate the whole group:

Select a member of the group and then press shift+G and press Group and it will select every other object in that group which you can now drag around, scale etc.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. When I created keyframes on the timeline while moving the whole object, only one of the object's keyframe was recorded.

Comment: Ty DevTim. Is it possible to add a group within a group? (Example, Weapons: Weapon1, Weapon2, Weapon3, etc)

Comment: How do I undo this grouping?  Ah, Object->Group->Remove From Group.

Answer (score 28):

You also can just parent them together. Select all Objects you want to group and than press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. All selected objects will now follow the object which was active during the Parenting process.

Comment: When I click on control + P it asks me "set parent to:" with a list of options. What do you recommend?

Comment: Usually you use Object Parent (Parent to: Object) the other settings are useful if you want to connect something without enheriting the rotation.

Comment: I think that the concept of parenting the objects in blender is quite better than the group because when you need a group you want to click and element of that group and move all the others together without the need of hitting shift+G or something similar.

Comment: Sometimes, it doesn't make sense for the objects to be grouped under any particular object. For example, if you had three columns, they should be at an equal level in the hierarchy for better organization. I like creating an empty to group them together.

Comment: Thanks for this. Took some tweaking (mainly the necessity to select the Parent lastly, in order to make the Siblings conform Parents movement), but I got it to work based on your advice.