# Rendering multiple smoke/fire domains

Tags: rendering

[image]

I have several smoke domains and sources that each start a fire at a different time (frame).

now it seems that I have an issue with black rectangles that appear, which is my domain.

After reading this question: [Is it possible to have more than one smoke simulation in the same scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-one-smoke-simulation-in-the-same-scene)
I've tried to put my domains and sources on different layers, but it didn't work.

Next I removed all my domains and added one huge domain.
This doesn't seem to produce the black rectangles, but now my smoke/fire all starts at the same time and the flames/fire are a bit different now.

Any suggestions on how I can render my multiple smoke/fire domains properly?
(in viewport preview everything was fine)

Comment: please upload a .blend

Comment: can't share the .blend file. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't already, you will want to assign a flow group for your smoke domain and place your emitter into a group.

First, select your emitter and [assign a group to it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33743/group-objects-in-blender) (alternative way to group would be to select the emitter, go to the **Object tab -> Groups**, assign a group and give it a name).

For your smoke domain, under the **Physics tab -> Smoke Groups**, set the **Flow Group** to the group you just made. This will prevent mixing of other emitters with that particular domain, allowing multiple domains to be in the same area and layer.

EDIT: One last thing I forgot to mention, make sure each domain has their own material.

And be warned: This may greatly increase render times, so consider placing them on separate layers regardless.