# DIfferent materials for individual smoke flows in same domain

Tags: materials, smoke-simulation

Ok so I have 3 smoke flows in a domain and I'm trying to get one of them to emit light, was considering using the colour attiribute to switch a mix shader but it seems like a horrible workaround, any suggestions would be really helpful

Comment: related: [Is it possible to have more than one smoke simulation in the same scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-one-smoke-simulation-in-the-same-scene) and [Rendering multiple smoke/fire domains](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57631/rendering-multiple-smoke-fire-domains)

Comment: What's wrong with using the color attribute as a "flow ID" of sorts? In Cycles you have total control over where that color attribute ends up in the final shader, so it's not like you have to "get rid of" the color later. Using color attributes to flag things is a pretty common practice in FX. It just makes life easier a lot of the time.

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing, need to optimise the the node setup but it works ok for now